# Transfer of NY Automobile Title without Co-owner Present/Available

Tags: car, transfer, title

I bought a car in the city of NY with my ex boyfriend. At the time of purchase I did not have a driver license so the registration came under his name and the loan under my name. I have been responsible for all the car/insurance payments. Since now I have my driver license I would like to change the registration to my name, but he is no where to be found. The last thing I heard about him is that they saw him in the street in very bad conditions. His license got suspended and now I don't know what to do. What are my options? What can I do? I don't want to lose all the money that I have put down and I don't want to mess up my credit!

The tittle as well as the registration came out under his name only. The car is currently under my possession.

Comment: You might talk to the bank - if they have a lien on the car they can take possession of the car and potentially sell it to you.